# How to do headsup notification on xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications

How can I show the notification as heads up notification on Xamarin Android. I got the notification working, but I don't know how to set to high priority so it can show up even when using other application. I used the plugin `Xam.Plugin.Notifier` for the NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android, if you want to show heads-up notification, you have to set the priority to High or Max: `builder.SetPriority (NotificationPriority.High);`
According to the source of Notifier plugin, there is no interface for the user to set the priority, so it does not support heads up notification. 
If you really want to use it, I can suggest 2 solutions for you:

1) Post an issue to the author of Notifier Plugin to modify it to support heads-up notification.

2) Create a notification yourself in Xamarin.Android instead of using the plugin. 
And in your code, you can write this:

```
builder.SetPriority (NotificationPriority.High);
```

or

```
builder.SetPriority (NotificationPriority.Max);
```

Comment: This is not working in android version 5.0.2 asus model

Comment: Just a heads up, notification priority is now set by channel priority and user settings in android 8 or greater https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications

Comment: builder can only be used when the app is in the foreground. The system tray handles notifications when in background I believe, so you can't use the builder.