# How to Show the Notification Popup on Over The screen in Xamarin Forms Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My local notification shows only status bar
Here is the example:
[image]

But I want to show the notification Over the screen 
Like This:

[image]

Here is my code for Local Notification:

```
public void GetLocalNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                Notification notification = new Notification();
                int notificationId;
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                {
                    String CHANNEL_ID = "com.ShipActivePOS.android";
                    string CharSequence = "MyChannel";
                    String Description = "This is my channel";
                    NotificationImportance importance = NotificationManager.ImportanceHigh;
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CharSequence, importance);
                    mChannel.Description = message;
                    mChannel.EnableLights(true);
                    mChannel.EnableVibration(true);
                    mChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });
                    mChannel.SetShowBadge(false);
                   // notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                    notificationId = 1100;

                    // string URGENT_CHANNEL = "com.ShipActivePOS.android.urgent";
                    // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(global::Android.App.Application.Context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetContentTitle("Sales123")
                        .SetContentText(message)
                        .SetChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppLogo);

                    // Build the notification:
                    Notification notificationO = builder.Build();

                    // Get the notification manager:                   

                    // Publish the notification:
                    notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notificationO);
                }
                else
                {
                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(global::Android.App.Application.Context)
                   .SetContentTitle(title)
                   .SetContentText(message)
                   .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppLogo);

                    builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
                    notification = builder.Build();
                    notificationId = 0;
                }
                // Publish the notification:
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

So how to show the notification top of the screen?
Is it possible to show the notification over the screen?

Comment: You want to show your notification first and then want it to be in the tray?

Comment: Yes.First show on display then tray

Comment: You may refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358060/how-to-do-headsup-notification-on-xamarin-android/54362657#54362657

Comment: Check the comment by Abby wang it has your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should change `Notification` priority or `NotificationChannel` importance.

The notification priority, set by `SetPriority()`. The priority determines how intrusive the notification should be on Android 7.1 and lower. (For Android 8.0 and higher, you must instead set the channel importance)

**On Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower:**

Set notification priority to `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH` or `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX`.

Set ringtone and vibrations - you can use SetDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)

**Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher:**

Set notification channel priority to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`

**Note:**
`Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH` and `Notification.PRIORITY_MAX` was deprecated in API level 26. use `NotificationCompat` instead.

For more information please read [Heads-up Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up).

Comment: You may need to uninstall/reinstall the app after making the priority change for it to take effect.